# Why does the upload to a GCP bucket work locally but not in the cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function written in Python that uploads a file from the file system (my C drive) to a bucket, runs a pandas conversion and downloads the resulting file back to the C drive.

When running in VS Code locally, it works perfectly. However, when I deploy the same code in the cloud console UI and test it there, I get a FileNotFound error. I have checked there isn't a typo and that the file exists.

[Image of error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y68Sk.png)

This is the code in my cloud function (the upload is done in the pandas_processing and upload_blob functions:

```
import functions_framework

from google.cloud import storage

import pandas as pd
import fastparquet

from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    # The ID of your GCS object
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    # The path to which the file should be downloaded
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Downloaded storage object {} from bucket {} to local file {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )



def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    # Optional: set a generation-match precondition to avoid potential race conditions
    # and data corruptions. The request to upload is aborted if the object's
    # generation number does not match your precondition. For a destination
    # object that does not yet exist, set the if_generation_match precondition to 0.
    # If the destination object already exists in your bucket, set instead a
    # generation-match precondition using its generation number.
    # generation_match_precondition = 0

    # blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, if_generation_match=generation_match_precondition)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        f"File {source_file_name} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}."
    )

 

@functions_framework.http
def pandas_processing(request):

    # it is mandatory initialize the storage client

    client = storage.Client()

    # Upload file from local machine or network
    upload_blob('gcp-python-files', 'C:\dev\drinks.csv', 'drinks.csv')

    #please change the file's URL

    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('gs://gcp-python-files/drinks.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR: " + str(e))
              
    print("List csv file header\n")
    print (df.head(3))
    
    df.to_parquet('gs://gcp-python-files/drinks.parquet',engine='fastparquet')
    print("Parquet exported to bucket")

    # Download file from gcp bucket to local machine or network
    download_blob('gcp-python-files', 'drinks.parquet', 'c:\dev\drinks.parquet')

    return f'end of function'
    
def list_buckets():
    """Lists all buckets."""

    bucket_list=[]
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()

    for bucket in buckets:
        print(bucket.name)
        bucket_list.append(bucket.name)

    return str(bucket_list)


def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """

    buckets = list_buckets()
    print(buckets)

    
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!\n\n{buckets}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("__\n")
    pandas_processing("https://europe-west2-gcp-python-test-380311.cloudfunctions.net/list-buckets")
```

I have searched for this specific issue but I can't anything that solves it.
I have the gcloud CLI installed and authenticated.
I have also run `gcloud auth application-default login` to create a credentials file.

I think those things only make your local environment work with the cloud and not vice versa.
How do I get the cloud console to recognise my C drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the code locally, your code can access your computer's local file system and read the file `C:\dev\drinks.csv`.

Note: that filename syntax works on Windows.

After you deploy your code to Cloud Functions, your code cannot access files on your computer's local file system. Therefore the file `C:\dev\drinks.csv` will not be found.

Also the path `C:\dev\drinks.csv` is invalid in Cloud Functions, which uses a Linux file system path syntax and not a Windows path syntax. The equivalent path is `/dev/drinks.csv`. However, just changing the path will not work if the file is not on the Cloud Function local file system.

If you are trying to use Cloud Functions to copy files from your computer's local file system to Cloud Storage, that will not work. Cloud Functions has no ability to access files on your computer.

You can include files from your local file system when you deploy your Cloud Function. That might be a useful step to learn more about Cloud Functions and deployments. Create a new question if that is your goal and you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So any interaction with the file system must be done locally.

Comment: @KenShabby - The code must run locally to interact with the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

You're uploading a file from `C:\dev\drinks.csv`, and while that file may exist on your own machine, it doesn't exist in the Cloud Functions environment. In fact, I'm pretty sure there isn't even a `C:\` in Cloud Functions, as they're running on a non-Windows environment.

If you want the file to be uploaded from the local Cloud Functions system, you'll need to make sure you upload it to the Cloud Functions environment, i.e. put the file in the same directory as your python source file.